Uploading this .gif doesn't work
Uploading this .gif doesn't work:


An error occurred, please try again.

Tested on Meta.SE, SU, and AskUbuntu with Chrome on Win10.

Interesting it's actually only 120k so not too big, I'll try to check other possible limitations then.

Well my best guess is the image dimensions which are huge (2373x1889) but only a developer can confirm. If you can resize that to e.g. 800px width (and respective height) this would probably work, and you can update the bug report with that info.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda thanks I'll let dev debug as resizing may also change other gif info.  But I guess you're correct.

(Disagreed with the edit proposal removing the screenshot: need to show error message, I should've edited it though instead since it's good to add the error message text)

@anonymous about the edit proposal: thanks but the screenshot shows more info: it's a Q (not A or chat), shows error message location+color, shows gif image preview, etc.

I had a look at this and was able to determine the root cause of the problem. The image in question is a large animated gif - 2373×1889 pixels with 114 frames. An image with these properties is not going to work.
We are working on providing better documentation to provide the upper-bounds limitations of images, as well as better error messages to indicate this in the near future.

Thanks, feature request: Allow higher-res gif

The "limited to 50 megapixels" for GIF is wrong. With X * Y * frames = megapixels 30 MB and 500 KB GIFs would have the same amount of megapixels. GIF does not store a full image per frame.

What's the rationale behind placing a limit on uploaded gifs in terms of pixels? (instead of bytes or frame dimensions)

Another feature request: GIF size limit is extremely small and easy to hit; increase it to allow for more practical uploads

A clearer error message has been added:

Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image



If OP's gif was 2373x1889, that's 4,482,597 pixels, or 4 megapixels. I don't think this message makes sense.

@isanae 4 megapixels x nb of frames > 50M pixels. See How can one count how many pixels a GIF image has via command line?

I don't think I've ever heard of megapixels used this way. It's usually the resolution of an image or the size of a camera sensor. I understand the math is correct, but the result is nonsense to me.

@isanae Agreed. What's the rationale behind placing a limit on uploaded gifs in terms of pixels? (instead of bytes or frame dimensions)
